# Count arrays comma separated values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this function to get an array of custom meta fields in WordPress

```
$my_var = get_meta_values( 'keywords' );
if( !empty( $my_var ) ) {
    $meta_counts = array();
    foreach( $my_var as $meta_value )
        $meta_counts[$meta_value] = ( isset( $meta_counts[$meta_value] ) ) ? $meta_counts[$meta_value] + 1 : 1;
}
print_r ($meta_counts);
```

The array it generates looks like

```
Array ( 
  [one, two, three, four and five, six and seven] => 1 
  [clean, ajax one, two three, four five] => 1 
  [] => 1 
  [this is a test, working] => 1 
  [asdfasdf] => 1 
  [last test] => 1 
)
```

How can I get a total count of each word or phrase that's separated by a comma. Not each individual word. In the array above the count would be 13

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a rewrite of `array_count_values`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get **13** words or phrases by this

```
$words = array_map('trim', explode(',', implode(',', array_keys($meta_counts))));
```

Comment: Will this always begin counting at 0? I realized I had an empty value in the example array above. I now tested with another array and see it begins counting at 0 such as `Array ( [0] => example1 [1] => example2 [2] => example3 [3] => four five )` where there are really 4 values. Is that how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called explode that lets you split the array.

Here is the link for it.

This should probably do some need.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Thanks I tried adding `var_dump( explode( ',', $meta_counts ) );` but the output is `array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" }` any advice on what to do?

Comment: Try this count() function 
eg.) echo count($var_name);

Answer (score 0):

Please try code given below

```
if( !empty( $my_var ) ) {
    $meta_counts = array();
    $total_count = 0;  
    foreach( $my_var as $meta_index=>$meta_value ){
         if(isset($meta_index) && !empty($meta_index)){
            $meta_index_arr = explode(',', $meta_index);
            $meta_counts[$meta_index] = count($meta_index_arr);   
            $total_count += $meta_counts[$meta_index];
         }else{
                          $meta_counts[$meta_index] = 0;
        }
     }

}
print_r ($meta_counts);
echo $total_count;
```

thanks