# Count total occurrences of each comma-separated value in an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, count, flatten

I want to extract count of each comma separated word from following array. Tried multiple functions (recursive/non-recursive) but nothing seems to work.

I would like `array_count_values()` to give the combined count of all keys as 3, but it gives just 1 for each.

**Actual Array**

```
Array
(
   [0] => Bangalore, Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur
   [1] => Bangalore, Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur
   [2] => Bangalore, Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur
)
```

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003099/count-arrays-comma-separated-values) seems to quite close & giving following output

```
Array
(
   [Bangalore] => 1
   [Chennai] => 1
   [Delhi] => 1
   [Gurgaon] => 1
   [Hyderabad] => 1
   [Kolkata] => 1
   [Mumbai / Navi Mumbai] => 1
   [Noida] => 1
   [Guntur] => 1
)
```

**Required Output**

```
Array
(
   [Bangalore] => 3
   [Chennai] => 3
   [Delhi] => 3
   [Gurgaon] => 3
   [Hyderabad] => 3
   [Kolkata] => 3
   [Mumbai / Navi Mumbai] => 3
   [Noida] => 3
   [Guntur] => 3
)
```

I know I m very close to required output but not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't resist coming up with a one-liner ;-)

```
$input = array(
    'foo, bar, baz',
    'foo, bar',
    'foo',
);

$output = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function($v) { return explode(', ', $v); }, $input)));
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 3
    [bar] => 2
    [baz] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `array_merge()` then `array_count_values()`.

**If your lines are array:**

```
$arr[] = array("Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "Mumbai / Navi Mumbai", "Noida", "Guntur");
$arr[] = array("Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "Mumbai / Navi Mumbai", "Noida", "Guntur");
$arr[] = array("Bangalore", "Chennai", "Delhi", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "Mumbai / Navi Mumbai", "Noida", "Guntur");

$comp = array();
foreach($arr as $vals) {
    $comp   =   array_merge($vals,$comp);
}

print_r(array_count_values($comp));
```

---

**If your lines are strings, you need to `explode()` as well:**

```
<?php
$arr[] = "Bangalore,Chennai,Delhi,Gurgaon,Hyderabad,Kolkata,Mumbai / Navi Mumbai,Noida,Guntur";
$arr[] = "Bangalore,Chennai,Delhi,Gurgaon,Hyderabad,Kolkata,Mumbai / Navi Mumbai,Noida,Guntur";
$arr[] = "Bangalore,Chennai,Delhi,Gurgaon,Hyderabad,Kolkata,Mumbai / Navi Mumbai,Noida,Guntur";

$comp = array();
foreach($arr as $vals) {
        $new    =   explode(",",$vals);
        $comp   =   array_merge($new,$comp);
    }

print_r(array_count_values($comp));
?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [Bangalore] => 3
    [Chennai] => 3
    [Delhi] => 3
    [Gurgaon] => 3
    [Hyderabad] => 3
    [Kolkata] => 3
    [Mumbai / Navi Mumbai] => 3
    [Noida] => 3
    [Guntur] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks lafor. It worked like charm. Many thanks. Though all other answers also worked but you have simple one liner :-)    Thanks to Herny & Rasclatt as well for sparing their time :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function soFnc($pcs,$arrResult) {
    foreach($pcs AS $val) {
        $val = trim($val);
        if(isset($arrResult[$val]))
            $arrResult[$val]++; 
        else
            $arrResult[$val]=1; 
    }   
    return $arrResult;
}

$arr = array();
$arr[] = 'Bangalore, Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur';
$arr[] = 'Bangalore, Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur';
$arr[] = 'Chennai, Delhi, Gurgaon, Hyderabad, Kolkata, Mumbai / Navi Mumbai, Noida, Guntur';

foreach($arr AS $item)
{

    if(!isset($arrResult))
        $arrResult=array();

    $pices = explode(",",$item);
    $arrResult = soFnc($pices,$arrResult);
}


echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrResult); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode-Flatten-Count.

Here is the modernized version of @lafor's answer  (PHP7.4 and higher).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/McU1j))

```
var_export(
    array_count_values(
        array_merge(
            ...array_map(fn($v) => explode(', ', $v), $input)
        )
    )
);
```