# get count of entries in multi-dimensional array with comma separated values- php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

*How to get count of entries in an array below?*

I tried [Count arrays comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003099/count-arrays-comma-separated-values) and didnot get desired solution.Please suggest a method.

**For below sample count is 11.**

```
$sample= Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
             [0] => Array ( [attendance] => 2012SD71,2010SD94 ) 
             [1] => Array ( [attendance] => 2003SD18,2003SD19 ) 
             [2] => Array ( [attendance] => 2003SD23,2003SD28 )) 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => 
[8] => 
[9] => 
[10] => 
[11] => 
[12] => 
[13] => Array ( 
              [0] => Array ( [attendance] => 2012SD81,2010SD84 ) 
              [1] => Array ( [attendance] => 2003SD18,2003SD19,2004SD14 ) ) [14] => 
[15] =>
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple recursive function should work that uses `explode()` and `array_merge()`:

```
function recurse($array,&$new)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                recurse($value,$new);
            }
            else {
                if(!empty($value)) {
                    $exp    =   array_filter(explode(',',$value));
                    $new    =   array_merge($new,$exp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
# Create a storage array
$new    =   array();
# Run the recursive function
recurse($sample,$new);
# Show count
print_r(count($new));
```